# JavaFX + SQLite: TableView - incompatible type

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I made a Maven JavaFX project + an SQLite database.

The database looks like this:
[image: Database Structure]

Now I can insert succesfully to this database from a form, but I can't show the data inside the TableView. I've followed some tutorials and made a class named ShopDetails:

```
public class ShopDetails {

private String name;
private String adress;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private String zipcode;
private String phonect;
private String phonearea;
private String phonemain;
}
```

Added the constructor and the getter-setters.
After that I made an ObservableList inside the Controller:

```
private ObservableList<ShopDetails> data;

private Connection conn = null;
private PreparedStatement pst = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
```

and connected to the database inside the initialize method, then I added

```
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Then I made a method to set the columns which data I want to show used this method:

```
 private void setCellTable(){
        columnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    //Other columns
    }
```

But it says:
[image: The error message I get]

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to provide the objecttype from which the field will be fetched

```
private void setCellTable(){
        columnName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ShopDetails,String>("name"));
}
```

In my application I created the table columns myself like

```
final TableColumn<OSTDataModel, String> taskStatus = new TableColumn<OSTDataModel, String>("Status");
taskStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OSTDataModel, String>("taskStatus"));
```

and the class `OSTDataModel` was the data structure which was holding my information like your `ShopDetails`